# Gulp watch failing with Spawn EACCES error

Tags: node.js, gulp, build-process, node-modules, gulp-watch

Any idea what is causing this error?

My Gulp Watch statement:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {

   gulp.watch('app/**/**/*.html', ['html-templates']).on('change', function(file) {
       gutil.log(gutil.colors.yellow.bold('HTML updated' + ' (' + file.path + ')'));
   });

   gulp.watch('app/assets/imgs/*.svg').on('change', function(file) {
       gutil.log(gutil.colors.magenta('SVG updated' + ' (' + file.path + ')'));
   });

   gulp.watch('bower_components/sass-smacss/sass/**/*.scss', ['app-css']).on('change', function(file) {
       gutil.log(gutil.colors.cyan.bold('CSS updated' + ' (' + file.path + ')'));
   });

   gulp.watch('highcharts/js/*.js', ['highcharts-js']).on('change', function(file) {
       gutil.log(gutil.colors.red.bold('JavaScript updated' + ' (' + file.path + ')'));
   });

   gulp.watch(paths.scripts, ['app-js']).on('change', function(file) {
       gutil.log(gutil.colors.red.bold('JavaScript updated' + ' (' + file.path + ')'));
   });
});
```

---

```
11:27:05] Error: spawn EACCES
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
  at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
  at exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
  at spawn (/Users/username/dashboard/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/node_modules/win-spawn/index.js:54:10)
  at module.exports (/Users/username/dashboard/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/index.js:89:13)
  at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/username/dashboard/gulpfile.js:246:12)
  at module.exports (/Users/username/dashboard/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
  at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/username/dashboard/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
  at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/username/dashboard/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
  at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/username/dashboard/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check:

- File permissions (on the watched files)
- Is there an existing `gulp.watch` running watching any of those files?
- Are all NPM dependencies correctly installed (less, sass, browserify, etc)?

Comment: I did, the error was actually from another developer who pulled the latest, turns out the problem was that he didn't have `sass` installed! Can you upgrade your answer to include checking for all dependancies installed?